# How to get irregular shapes of parameters in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, variables, parameters

I want to multiply (Hadamard product) a matrix with a trainable tensor of the same size in TensorFlow. I.e. every non-zero element of the matrix is supposed to have a trainable multiplier. 
How do I do this?

The following also 'trains' 0-elements of the matrix.

```
weights = tf.get_variable('weights', [len_matrix,len_matrix], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

result = weights * matrix
```

Comment: if the matrix has zeros, why do you care about non-zero multipliers, since `x*0=0`?

Comment: I want to facilitate and accelerate training. The number of parameters is unnecessarily high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module named `tf.sparse` which has optimized operations on sparse matrices, however, from what I found, it does not have a sparse variable implementation.

The only way that comes to my mind is to essentially flatten the sparse matrix without the zeros, then you can use a simple 1D variable. This assumes you know the sparse matrix in advance.

```
a = np.array([[1.4, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -4.5, 0.0]])
ix = np.argwhere(a == 0).T
flat_a = a[ix[0], ix[1]]

weights = tf.get_variable('weights', [len(flat_a)], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

result = weights * flat_a

... # when you want to obtain the full result matrix back

flat_result = sess.run(result)
result = np.zeros(a.shape)
result[ix[0], ix[1]] = flat_result
```